# How do you remove parts of an element within a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

I have a data set that is something like:

`time={-2_ms, -1_ms, 0_ms, 1_ms, 2_ms};`

How do I drop the _ms part such that its just a list of numbers?

Comment: Are those strings in your dataset? You can't have underscores in data or variable names: they have a predefined meaning in MMA (they refer to `Blank` patterns). How are you generating or importing the dataset?

Comment: Yes, I don't want underscores in my data. As stated in the question, I just want the values. The data is imported and I can't control how the data is exported.

Comment: OK got it, however the way you import the data is critical here. Can you please share the original form in which the data is given to you, and the code you used to import it?

Comment: We understand that you want to remove the underscores. But information often gets lost when people take stuff from their MMA notebook and paste it here. For example, is the expression really `"{-2_ms,-1_ms,0_ms,1_ms,2_ms}"`? Or is it `{"-2_ms", "-1_ms", "0_ms", "1_ms", "2_ms"}`? Or is it `List[Times[-2, Blank[ms]], Times[-1, Blank[ms]], 0, Blank[ms], Times[2, Blank[ms]]]`? Also, this is a very strange expression--it's almost certainly not a semantically valid representation even though it doesn't generate errors. So, if you give us more context, we can do a better job of helping you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

```
list = {"-2_ms", "-1_ms", "0_ms", "1_ms", "2_ms"};
Map[StringReplace[#, "_ms" -> ""] &, list] // ToExpression 
(*{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}*)
```

or

```
Map[StringDelete[#, "_ms" ] &, list] // ToExpression
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {"-2_ms", "-1_ms", "0_ms", "1_ms", "2_ms"};

StringSplit[list, "_"] // Map[First] // ToExpression
```

---

> {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}